# window.open() doesn't work with android nor with ipad

Tags: javascript

I have a dynamically generated div with certain class. I used .print() to get generated tables and lists inside that div to show nicely for printing on windows. However, this doesn't work on ipad nor on android. 
Is there a better way to export generated div content onto pdf or some other way that will be displayed on windows and mobile?

```
         _printThis: function (){
            var text = $(".divClass")[0].outerHTML;
            var popup = window.open("", "popup");
            popup.document.body.innerHTML = text;
            popup.focus(); //required for IE
            if($(".divClass")){
                $(".divClass").remove();
            }

            popup.print();
            popup.close();
        }
```

i looked at jsPDF but it cuts off my content and doesn't support CSS :(

Comment: Many browsers block popup windows that aren't directly user-initiated.

Comment: In order to 'fix' this, make sure this is triggered from a button onClick or anchor (but prefer buttons, since onClick on an anchor doesnt make much sense, semantically)

Comment: Thank you, I added the test for popup blocker to see if it is enabled on user's machine / tablet and it did the trick. If blocker is not set, works great.